# Eclipse Juno does not Mark Occurrences after using "Open declaration"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 for Java and Android development, And I'm having difficulties in the Mark Occurrences feature.

The feature works perfectly until I press `Cmd` + `Click` to Open method/class declaration, Then it stops working in the file I navigated from. I have to close the file and open it again in order for the Mark occurrences to work properly.

Is there a way to fix the marking without closing and opening the file every time i use the open declaration feature?

Comment: Have you tried it on the current version?

Comment: Yes I have, and it works fine but last time I updated I had problems with the workspace and I had to create a new one, so I just need to resolve this for now until I'm ready for updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary fix, I could navigate from the page that has the error to any other app and navigate back to it (`Cmd` + `Tab` twice), the occurrences work like that.

I have searched for a fix inside Juno, but the only fix i found is to update to the newer version of Eclipse.